# Hebrew phrase/term and pronunciation for "the Lord is my high ridge" from Psalm 18.2

Tags: words, hebrew, translation, tehilim-psalms

I would really appreciate to know the original Hebrew phrase/term and its pronunciation for "the Lord is my high ridge" from Psalm 18.2

Comment: Hi hashim and welcome to MY! Mi Yodeya works a bit differently than other sites, so you might want to take a look at our [tour] to see how the site works. Hope to see you around!

Answer (score 3):

It's [God's name](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetragrammaton), followed by the word "סַלְעִי". [We don't use the correct pronunciation of this one of God's names](/a/9969/170), substituting something like [/ʔadoˈnaj/](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet). "סַלְעִי" is something like [/salˈʕi/](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet). But pronunciation varies from person to person, as in any language.

(Incidentally, this phrase appears in the third, not the second, verse of that psalm. For some reason, most Christian bibles exclude the incipit when numbering verses in Psalms.)

Answer (score 1):

> :יְהֹוָה֘ סַֽלְעִ֥י וּמְצֽוּדָתִ֗י וּמְפַ֫לְטִ֥י אֵלִ֣י צ֖וּרִי אֶֽחֱסֶה־בּ֑וֹ מָֽגִנִּ֖י וְקֶ֥רֶן יִ֜שְׁעִ֗י מִשְׂגַּבִּֽי
>
> O Lord, my rock and my fortress and my rescuer; my God, my rock, I will take refuge in Him; my shield and the horn of my salvation, my refuge.

(From [Chabad.org](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16239/jewish/Chapter-18.htm#v=3))

The transliteration of this verse is below. The slash indicates a space between a word. Note that this does not reflect a more ancient pronunciation, but rather the common pronunciation that used in Israel today.

Ah-doh-nai / sal-ee / oo-mih-tzoo-dah-tee / oo-mih-fal-tee / ay-lee / tzoo-ree / eh-cheh-seh / boh / mah-gee-nee / vih-keh-ren / yeesh-ee / mees-gah-bee

The words "O Lord, my rock" are **Ah-doh-nai / sal-ee**. And they look like this in Hebrew: יהוה סלעי